# Maintaining Focus While Not On Top Java

Tags: java, swing, focus, awt

I'm looking to do something which may be impossible; in Java (1.6 running on Windows 7, since this is platform-dependent), I want to have a window appear over another window, but not steal focus from the triggering component.  In the example attached below, I'd like to be able to be able to click on the text field, have the new pop up appear in front, but maintain focus on the text field.  What I instead notice is that I get the panel to the front, but do not get focus on the text field again.

I'm primarily wondering if this is possible (normally the front Window has focus in Windows, so I'm leaning towards probably not).  If not, but someone has opinions on a good workaround, I'm open ears.

Example:

```
public class PopUpExample
{
    // Global toolkit listener.
    enum PopUp
    {
        INSTANCE;

        private PopUpWindow m_popUp;
        private JTextComponent m_textComponent;

        public void initialize(PopUpWindow p)
        {
            m_popUp = p;

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener( new AWTEventListener()
            {
                public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e)
                {
                    // Ensure event is a focus gain event.
                    if (( e instanceof FocusEvent )
                            && ((FocusEvent)e).getID()==FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED)
                    {
                        // If it is on a text field, make the pop up appear, but maintain focus on the text field
                        if ( (e.getSource() instanceof JTextComponent) )
                        {
                            m_textComponent = (JTextComponent)e.getSource();
                            // FIXME Code below here should set the button on top, yet leave the text field with focus.
                            m_popUp.setAlwaysOnTop( true );
                            m_popUp.setFocusable( false );
                            m_popUp.setVisible( true );
                            m_textComponent.requestFocus();
                            // end FIXME
                        }
                        // Otherwise, make the pop up disappear (if it isn't the pop up itself).
                        else if (((JComponent)e.getSource()).getRootPane().getComponent(0) instanceof PopUpWindow)
                        {
                            m_popUp.setVisible( false );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK);
        }
    }

    // Pop up window that isn't focusable
    class PopUpWindow extends JFrame
    {
        public PopUpWindow()
        {
            super();

            BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
            this.setLayout( layout );

            this.setMinimumSize( new Dimension( 100, 100 ) );

            JButton button = new JButton("WantOnFront");
            button.setFocusable( false );
            this.add( button, BorderLayout.CENTER );

            this.setFocusable( false );
        }
    }

    // Main application window.
    class GuiWindow extends JFrame
    {
        public GuiWindow()
        {
            super();

            BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
            this.setLayout( layout );

            this.setMinimumSize( new Dimension( 400, 400 ) );

            JButton button = new JButton("defaultFocusButton");
            this.add( button, BorderLayout.CENTER );

            JTextField textField = new JTextField("WantToMaintainFocusWhenClicked");
            this.add( textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        }
    }

    // Setup code
    public PopUpExample()
    {
        new GuiWindow().setVisible( true );
        PopUp.INSTANCE.initialize( new PopUpWindow() );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        new PopUpExample();
    }
}
```

Comment: Most important: what's your motivation for doing this? What effect are you trying to achieve and why? If we better understand your overall problem, we'll likely be better at offering a decent solution. Also note that the child window should most definitely not be a JFrame but rather a JDialog.

Comment: I wanted to abstract away my goals from the problem in question (as I felt it would just bloat down the question), but, if you feel like it's helpful info, I'm making a virtual keyboard. The pop up that appears when you select a text field is actually a button that can be pressed to display a virtual keyboard. However, I want the text field to maintain focus, because physical keyboards should still be allowed to type in there.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Camickr is a Swing genius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> have the new pop up appear in front, but maintain focus on the text field.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(...);
dialog.setFocusableWindowState( false );
...
dialog.setVisible( true );
```

Comment: Did not know about JDialog setFocusableWindowState( bool );

Thank you very much for your quick reply.